# onItemClickListener only opens first item's span menu

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Im trying to do a spannable ListView. When you click on an item in ListView it should span and reveal two buttons. So far I have managed to create CustomAdapter for that.

My problem is that when i click on an item always the first item on ListView is spanned. How to fix this and how to set onClickListener to those two buttons.

My ListView Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView productList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        productList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Product product= (Product) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Button CheckButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);
                Button DeleteButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
                CheckButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        dbhandler=new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);
       // getProductsFromDb();
        adapter= new CustomAdapter(this,productnames);
        productList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    public void addNewProduct(View view){
        EditText userInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        userInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String productname=userInput.getText().toString();

        if(productname.equals(""))return;

        Product product=new Product();
        product.set_productname(productname);
        product.set_checked(false);
        productnames.add(product);
        //dbhandler.addProduct(product);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        userInput.setText("");
        //getProductsFromDb();
```

CustomAdapter:

```
 CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productNames) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_list_row ,productNames);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row,parent,false);

        final Product singleProduct=getItem(position);
        TextView productName=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.ProductName);
        Button CheckButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);
        Button DeleteButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);

        productName.setText(singleProduct.get_productname());


        return customView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post your `custom_list_row` layout, but what I can guess from your code is that in that layout you have a ViewGroup or View (Let's assume that it is the TextView to display the product name in your code) for item and 2 buttons below which have VISIBILITY set to GONE at first. Then what you want is that when users click on the item, you will set the 2 buttons below that item to VISIBLE. Here are one way to do so:

1. Remove the setOnItemClickListener on the productList from Activity
2. In the getView() method of your CustomAdapter set onClickListener to the product name view. Something like this:

   TextView productName=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.ProductName);

   Button CheckButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);

   Button DeleteButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);

   ```
   productName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       CheckButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: and if I want to add onclickListener to those two buttons where should i Do that?

Comment: On the CustomAdapter getView() also. That is where you have reference to the buttons at a specific position.